# Range is product then so must the operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-information

Consider an operator $\eta$ on the (tensor) product of Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ such that its range is of the form $V_1\otimes V_2$. Does this imply that $\eta$ must be a product operator, i.e., of the form $\eta = A\otimes B$?

**Followup Question** (in response to @David Gao's counterexample). What if the range is such that $\dim V_2 =1$?

**Background**. In physics, we often consider Hermitian operators (called the Hamiltonian $H$) defined on tensor products $\bigotimes_{i\in V}\mathcal{H}_i$ on some set of vertices $V$, consisting of local interactions in the sense that $H=\sum_{e} h_e$ where $h_e$ are Hermitian operator defined on $\mathcal{H}_i\otimes \mathcal{H}_j$ for some $e=ij$ (and thus induces a graph structure on the vertices $V$). I was curious what it meant for each local interaction $h_e$ to be "entangled", i.e., not a trivial product operator.

Comment: I’ve edited my answer to show that the answer to your followup question is still no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, choose a unitary operator $\eta$ on $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $\eta(e_1 \otimes e_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$. Since it’s a unitary, its range is $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$. But it cannot be written as $A \otimes B$ as otherwise $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2) = \eta(e_1 \otimes e_1) = Ae_1 \otimes Be_1$ is decomposable as a tensor product, which is not possible.

---

The answer is still no even assuming $\mathrm{dim}(V_2) = 1$. In fact, to settle this completely, the following is an example showing that the answer is no in $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$ (and therefore the answer is no whenever both $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ have dimension at least $2$) even when $\mathrm{dim}(V_1) = \mathrm{dim}(V_2) = 1$. Simply let $\eta$ be defined as the orthogonal projection onto $\mathrm{span}\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)\}$ composed with the map that sends $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$ to $e_1 \otimes e_1$. The range is $\mathrm{span}\{e_1\} \otimes \mathrm{span}\{e_1\}$. If $\eta = A \otimes B$, then $\eta^\ast = A^\ast \otimes B^\ast$ and $\eta^\ast (e_1 \otimes e_1) = A^\ast e_1 \otimes B^\ast e_1$, but $\eta^\ast (e_1 \otimes e_1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$.

Comment: I should point out that if $\eta$ is assumed normal (or better yet, self-adjoint), and either $\mathrm{dim}(V_1) = 1$ or $\mathrm{dim}(V_2) = 1$, then the answer is yes. But as my first example shows, normality by itself is not enough. (I realized my previous comment on taking logarithm of the first example doesn't really make sense, so that part is now removed.)

Comment: Though the conclusion that self-adjoint does not guarantee the result is still true. Indeed, if $\eta$ is defined by $\eta(e_1 \otimes e_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$, $\eta(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)) = e_1 \otimes e_2$, and $\eta(h) = h$ whenever $h$ is orthogonal to both $e_1 \otimes e_2$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$. Then $\eta$ is a self-adjoint unitary that cannot be written as a tensor product.

Comment: So, to summarize, the only way to guarantee a result like the OP's desired conclusion is to require $\eta$ to be normal (or more specifically, self-adjoint) and require either $V_1$ or $V_2$ to have dimension $1$.